# Получить int >> float

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Как из `int` (10) получить `float` (10.00)?

Варианты с добавлением `$string .= ".00";` не интересуют.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Привести переменную к float/double типу можно при помощи одного из способов явного приведения типов

```
<?php
$number = (double)10;
echo gettype($number);
```

или так

```
<?php
$number = 10;
settype($number, 'float');
echo gettype($number);
```

Если вас интересует именно форматирование, то можно воспользоваться функцией `sprintf()`

```
<?php
echo sprintf('%0.2f', 10);
```

или `printf()`

```
<?php
printf('%0.2f', 10);
```

Comment: всё ровно в результате 10, а не 10.00

Comment: @ikeria, может попробовать round((float)10, 2);

Comment: @ikerya, поправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. А есть ещё варианты?

Comment: @ikerya, вариант DanielOlivo - тоже вполне себе рабочий, не успел его привести :)

Comment: `Все забыли про number_format :(`

(c) modal

Comment: @ikerya, кстати, да, тоже вариант.

Comment: @ikerya Вариант очень хорош  DanielOlivo